# Adding a ribbed texture to object (eg. a vase)

Tags: modeling

I’m new to Blender and have decided to design some basic objects, such as vases. For that I use the screw modifier.

I want these vases to have a texture on the outside. In this case a ribbed texture similar to the image below.

Honestly… I really have no idea where to start looking. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with texturing, unwrapping, normal maps?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can either model all these stripes for real or fake them with height map or bump map, which will make your object much lighter, you first need to choose which solution you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can "model" these ribbons with a *Displacement* modifier and a wave texture.

**1. Prepare the model**

Start with a low poly vase. If you're happy with the shape, make a backup copy. Then add and apply a *Soldify* modifier. This way you can select the outer faces where you want to place the ribbons. Select the faces and add them to a vertex group:

[image: model of the vase]

**2. Create the Displacement Image**

The ribbons are created by a black and white image. You can create one with Gimp/Photoshop or just bake it in Blender.

To bake it, use the *Wave Texture* node, set up the mapping to rotate and scale it. Then bake the image as *Emit* type through an *Emission* node. The *Color Ramp* node has an extra color stop in the middle with a`#808080` grey value to get a smooth transition from black to white:

[image: baking wave texture]

**3. Create the Ribbons With a Displacement Modifier**

Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to the model. The first *Subdivision Surface* modifier (level 2) in the example is just to smooth the very low-poly base mesh. The level 4 *Subdivision Surface* modifier is used to create a lot of vertices (~450,000) for the *Displacement* modifier. A *MultiRes* modifier should work, too.

To get the ribbons finally, add a *Displacement* modifier, create a texture and use the create image for it. Lower the *Strength*, and set the *Coordinates* to `UV`, and set the vertex group. Now you can scale and rotate the ribbons in the *UV Editor* as you like.

[image: displacement setup]

**4. Bake a Normal Map For Low-Poly Version**

The creation of a low-poly version is easy because you already have it. Just duplicate the model and remove the level 4 *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Then UV Unwrap the low-poly model (important) and bake the normal map (*Selected to Active*). Of course, if you used a *MultiRes* modifier, bake it first, then remove it.

**Result**

On the left is the high-poly version (~450k verts). On the right is the low-poly version (~1,800 verts). Base mesh without *Subdivision Surface* modifiers has 118 verts.

[image: high and low-poly versions]

Comment: Amazing! I don't know how to thank you. I am new to the world of Blender, and thanks to your explanation I have not only achieved my goal, but discovered many new possibilities within Blender. Thanks for the great information!